# How to change the order of integration of $\int_{-1}^1dx \int_{1-x^2}^{2-x^2}f(x,y)dy$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

How to change the order of integration:

$$\int_{-1}^1dx \int_{1-x^2}^{2-x^2}f(x,y)dy$$

I tried to sketch the area and got:

[image]

Where red line is $x^2< 1$, green lines are $1-y$ and $2-y$. However I can't seem to get it right...

The solution should be:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your diagram is not correct. The region is bound by curves $y = 1 - x^2, y = 2 - x^2, x = -1, x = 1$. The correct diagram is as given below -

[image]

The given solution has three split integrals - first integral corresponds to sub-region $1$, second to sub-region $2$ and third to sub-region $3$.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to do this kind of things is to rewrite integral boundaries into indicator functions:
$$I:=\int_{-1}^1dx\int_{1-x^2}^{2-x^2}dy\, f(x,y)=\int_{-1}^1dx\int_{0}^{2}dy\, f(x,y)\chi_{1-x^2<y<2-x^2}$$
where $\chi_\text{condition}$ is 1 if the condition is met and 0 otherwise.
Then you can switch easily
$$I=\int_{0}^{2}dy\int_{-1}^1dx\, f(x,y)\chi_{1-x^2<y<2-x^2}
   =\int_{0}^{2}dy\int_{-1}^1dx\, f(x,y)\chi_{1-y<x^2<2-y}$$
Given that the lower bound $1-y$ for $x^2$ changes sign at $y=1$, it makes sense to cut the integral on $y$ at $y=1$:
$$I=\int_{0}^{1}dy\int_{-1}^1dx\, f(x,y)\chi_{1-y<x^2}+
    \int_{1}^{2}dy\int_{-1}^1dx\, f(x,y)\chi_{x^2<2-y}$$
Notice how one could drop the condition $x^2<2-y$ in the first integral, and $1-y<x^2$ in the second, as these are now always true.

In the second integral, the condition is equivalent to $-\sqrt{2-y}<x<\sqrt{2-y}$, and these bounds are within $[-1,1]$, so things are easy: we can replace the indicator function with the new bounds. In the first integral  the condition is equivalent to $x>\sqrt{1-y}$ or $x<-\sqrt{1-y}$. This splits the first integral into two parts:
$$I=\int_{0}^{1}dy\int_{-1}^{-\sqrt{1-y}}dx \,f(x,y)+\int_{0}^{1}dy\int_{\sqrt{1-y}}^1dx \,f(x,y)+\int_{1}^{2}dy\int_{-\sqrt{2-y}}^{\sqrt{2-y}}dx\, f(x,y).$$
This is the relation you give.

Comment: We haven't taken the indicator function yet, where can I learn more about it? Is it difficult?

Comment: How did you get the bound from 0 to 2 when you used the indicator?

Comment: It seems clear from the original form that y cannot be larger than 2 or smaller than 0, so you might as well put those bounds from the begining. But you could also start with putting $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ as bounds. Of course, at some points doing the computation, it must become clear that there is no contribution for $y$ outside $[0,2]$.